# Can I retag SPIR to SPIR-V on appropriate posts?

Tags: discussion, tags

The're only 9 posts with SPIR tag, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spir,

Some of these might actually be fine, however SPIR does not imply the same thing as SPIR-V since the two are actually pretty different and served different purposes.  99% of the time, questions about SPIR will not apply at all to SPIR-V. SPIR1.0,1.2, and 2.0 have since been pushed aside in OpenCL in favor of SPIR-V, which is also used in Vulkan and is and option now for use in OpenGL.  Unfortunately to the uninitiated the SPIR tag looks like it would apply to SPIR-V.

In vulkan and opengl, SPIR is never the appropriate tag, as SPIR1.0->2.0 were never used in either API.  In OpenCL, sometimes it is the correct tag, but now that SPIR-V has been introduced, it makes things even more confusing. I'm not sure if there is a better way to tag SPIR however.  Luckily it looks like all three posts that don't also tag with Vulkan are probably appropriately tagged from an SPIR perspective.

I know its discouraged to only edit posts to change tags, so what can be done on the posts with OpenGL and Vulkan that clearly shouldn't use SPIR-V, can I re-tag them in this case?

Comment: I have no clue about this, but my suggestion is that you try to ask [Nicol Bolas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/734069/nicol-bolas), he is both an active user on meta but also top answerer in both of those tag, ping him on one of his questions/answers with link to this meta post and blame me. (then delete comment if you see him answering or commenting back)

Comment: @PetterFriberg I think I just saw Nicolas Bolas Edit the tags in real time and took care of all the ones I mentioned after I pinged him.

Comment: Perfect finally a happy ending on meta :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> can I re-tag them in this case?

You have less than 2K rep. While you can make make tag-only edits to posts, you don't get rep for when their reviewed.

But since my edits don't have to be reviewed, I have already cleaned up the SPIR tag (and edited the tag wiki). Bringing this up on MSO was the right move.

Comment: To be clear, sub-2k users *can* make tag-only edit suggestions to posts... they just don't get reputation for them, and such edits should only happen if there's truly no other thing in the post that needs fixing.

Comment: @TylerH actually, they do get reputation for such edits. You get 2 reputation for any edit suggestion so long as you haven't obtained 1k rep due edit suggestions.

Comment: @Braiam I am pretty sure Shog posted an update a year or two ago removing the rep update for tag-only edits but I could be mistaken.

Comment: @TylerH if it changed, then the help center is lying https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: @Braiam I think I remember what the change was - tag-only edits don't count toward the editor badges.

Comment: @TylerH that one is pretty old. Yeah, I remember it. Only for copy editor badge https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/49/copy-editor

Comment: @pnuts: "*the tag search page for [spir] displays (due to automatic truncation): "FOR SPIR-V. ..."*" What is this "tag search page"? Can you provide a link to it?

Comment: @pnuts ... I have no idea how to even begin to fix that problem.

Comment: @pnuts: I've fixed the tag wiki for SPIR to truncate reasonably.